# Auto-resize Figure in Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am looking for some option to automatically resize the figures that I am generating using seaborn (barplots, countplot, boxplot). I am creating all the plots in one shot, but the issue is, in some of the graphs labels & bars are tightly packed because some of the columns have too many categorical values. I am using the below code:

```
for col in dff.drop(target_col_name, axis=1).columns:
    if ((dff[col].nunique() / len(dff[col])) < threshold):
        
        ax = sns.countplot(x=dff[col], hue= dff[target_col_name] )
        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
        
        pd.crosstab(index = dff[col], 
                    columns = dff[target_col_name], normalize = 'index').plot.bar()
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
    elif (dff[col].dtype == 'int64' or dff[col].dtype == 'float64'):
        sns.boxplot(dff[target_col_name], dff[col])
```

[image: Looks Fine]

[image: Overlapping content]

One solution is to increase all the figsize for all figures or use another if condition to target specific columns that have more categorical values and increase the size of those figures.

But I am looking for a more flexible solution so that all the figures get resized automatically based on the information in them.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a plotly in-built function "figure()" that you can use to alter the size of charts. All you need do is declare it right before the code for your chats.

For instance, `plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))` alters the height and width of the chart to 12 and 5 respectively.